# Dealing with array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-flip

I am trying to **sort** the following arrays.

**Array(s)**

```
$fruits = array(
    'mango',
    'mango red',
    'mango yellow',
    'orange',
    'banana',
    'apple',
    'apple red',
    'apple green',
);
```

**What I have done:**

```
$data = array_flip( $fruits ); // flip array
$data = array_fill_keys( array_keys( array_flip( $data ) ), 'array(),' ); // fill array value: "array(),"

print_r( $data );
```

**I want this result:**

```
$fruits = array(
    'mango'      => array(
        'red'       => array(),
        'yellow'    => array(),
    ),
    'orange'    => array(),
    'banana'    => array(),
    'apple'     => array(
        'red'       => array(),
        'green'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

**Hope you can understand the question. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, and split the string. Then recursively create nested arrays.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($fruits as $f) {
    $f_array = explode(' ', $f);
    $start = &$result;
    foreach ($f_array as $word) {
        if (!isset($start[$word])) {
            $start[$word] = array();
        }
        $start = &$start[$word];
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/vwY5Lf)

Comment: `$fruits = array(
 'apple green one',
 'apple green two',
);` // best answer

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach(for your current array):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    $parts = explode(' ', $fruit);
    if (count($parts) == 1) {
        $result[$fruit] = [];
    } elseif (isset($result[$parts[0]])) {
        $result[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = [];
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This doesn't generalize to more than 2 words in each fruit.

Comment: @Barmar, I know that, that's why I wrote *for your current array*